# How do I get the file name corresponding to an NFS file handle on Linux?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have tcpdump output of some NFS traffic, it shows which file handles are being read or written.  I'd like to know which files they correspond to.  There's got to be an existing tool which will list file names and file handles for all files in a directory, no?

My backup plan is to start tcpdump, then mount the datastore and ls the files, then dig out the filename/file handle pairs from the NFS lookup commands in the tcpdump.  But that's pretty time consuming and manual.